# Is making smaller functions generally more efficient memory-wise since variables get deallocated more frequently?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

Is dividing the work into 5 functions as opposed to one big function more memory efficient in C since at a given time there are fewer variables in memory, as the stack-frame gets deallocated more often? Does it depend on the compiler, and optimization? if so in what compilers is it faster?

Answer given there are a lot of local variables and the stack frames comes from a centralized main and not created on the top of each other.

I know other advantages of breaking out the function into smaller functions. Please answer this question, only in respect to memory usage.

Comment: Please don't structure your code to minimize memory. Do it in a way that makes the most sense to you and is easiest to understand. Micro-optimizations are a waste of your time.

Comment: Is your computer built in 1970?  Is it a limited architecture like a [PDP11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11_architecture)?

Comment: No, but it is more efficient if it makes them easier to read. Programmers are a lot more expensive than computer memory.

Comment: You'll gain much more of structuring your data properly to minimise cash misses. As for the variable spills, a decent compiler should do a much better job in keeping variables that are in use close to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It *might* reduce "high water mark" of stack usage for your program, and if so that *might* reduce the overall memory requirement of the program.

Yes, it depends on optimization. If the optimizer inlines the function calls, you might well find that all the variables of all the functions inlined are wrapped into one big stack frame. Any compiler worth using is capable of inlining[*], so the fact that it can happen doesn't depend on compiler. Exactly when it happens, will differ.

If your local variables are small, though, then it's fairly rare for your program to use more stack than has been automatically allocated to you at startup. Unless you go past what you're given initially, how much you use makes no difference to overall memory requirements.

If you're putting great big structures on the stack (multiple kilobytes), or if you're on a machine where a kilobyte is a lot of memory, then it might make a difference to overall memory usage. So, if by "a lot of local variables" you mean few dozen `int`s and pointers then no, nothing you do makes any significant difference. If by "a lot of local variables" you mean a few dozen 10k buffers, or if your function recurses very deep so that you have hundreds of levels of your few dozen `int`s, then it's a least possible it could make a difference, depending on the OS and configuration.

The model that stack and heap grow towards each other through general RAM, and the free memory in the middle can be used equally by either one of them, is obsolete. With the exception of a very few, very restricted systems, memory models are not designed that way any more. In modern OSes, we have so-called "virtual memory", and stack space is allocated to your program one page at a time. Most of them automatically allocate more pages of stack as it is used, up to a configured limit that's usually very large. A few don't automatically extend stack (Symbian last I used it, which was some years ago, didn't, although arguably Symbian is not a "modern" OS). If you're using an embedded OS, check what the manual says about stack.

Either way, the only thing that affects total memory use is how many pages of stack you need at any one time. If your system automatically extends stack, you won't even notice how much you're using. If it doesn't, you'll need to ensure that the program is given sufficient stack for its high-water mark, and that's when you might notice excessive stack use.

In short, this is one of those things that in theory makes a difference, but in practice that difference is almost always insignificant. It only matters if your program uses massive amounts of stack relative to the resources of the environment it runs in.

[*] People programming in C for PICs or something, using a C compiler that is basically a non-optimizing assembler, are allowed to be offended that I've called their compiler "not worth using". The stack on such devices is so different from "typical" systems that the answer is different anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I think in most cases the area of memory allocated for the stack (for the entire program) remains constant. The amount *in use* will change based on the depth of call stack and that amount would be less when fewer variables are used (but note that function calls push the return address and stack pointer also).

Also it depends on how the functions are called. If two functions are called in series, for example, and the stack of the first is popped before the call to the second, then you'll be using less of the stack..but if the first function calls the second then you're back to where you were with one big function (plus the function call overhead).

Answer (score 0):

There's no memory allocation on stack - just moving the stack pointer towards next value. While stack size itself is predefined. So there's no difference in memory usage (apart of situations when you get stack overflow).

Comment: moving the stack pointer up means using up more memory. Stack and heap grow towards each other; using more stack space or heap space means basically the same thing: less free memory.

Comment: Well, pages are not physically used, but they are reserved and deducted from system commit limit. afaik

Answer (score -1):

Yes, in the same vein that using a finer coat of paint on a jet plane increases its aerodynamic properties. Ok, that's a bad analogy, but the point is that if there is ever a question of making things clear and telegraphic or trying to use more functions, go with telegraphic. In most cases these are not mutually exclusive anyway as the beginners tend to give subroutines or functions too much to do.

In terms of memory I think that if you are truly splitting up up work (f, then g, then h) then you will see some minute available memory increases but if these are interdependent then you will not.

As @Joel Burget says, memory management is not really a consideration in code structuring.

Just my take.

Answer (score -1):

Splitting a huge function into smaller ones does have its benefits, among them is *potentially more optimized* memory usage.

Say, you have this function.

```
void huge_func(int input) {
    char a[1024];
    char b[1024];
    // do something with input and a
    // do something with input and b
}
```

And you split it to two.

```
void func_a(int input) {
    char a[1024];
    // do something with input and a
}

void func_b(int input) {
    char b[1024];
    // do something with input and b
}
```

Calling `huge_func` will take at least 2048 bytes of memory, and calling `func_a` then `func_b` achieves the same outcome with about half less memory. However, if inside `func_a` you call `func_b`, the amount of memory used is about the same as `huge_func`. Essentially, as what @sje397 wrote.

I might be wrong to say this but I do not think there is any compiler optimization that could help you reduce the usage of stack memory. I believe the layout of stack memory must ensure that sufficient memory is reserved for all declared variables, whether used or not.